# Insert distinct records in the table while updating the remaining columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is actually a form to update the team members who work for a specific client, When i deselect a member then it's status turns to `0`.

I have a table with all unique records. table consists of four columns -

```
first column is `id` which is unique and auto_incremented. 
second column is `client_id`.
third column is `member_id`. (these second and third columns together make the primary key.)
fourth column is `current` which shows the status (default is 1.).
```

Now i have a form which sends the values of `client_id` and `member_id`. But this forms also contains the values that are already in the table `BUT NOT ALL`.

I need a query which

```
(i) `INSERT` the values that are not already in the table,

(ii) `UPDATE` the `current` column to value `0` which are in the table but not in the form values.
```

here is a screenshot of my form.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If (select count(*) from yourtable where  client_id =  and member_id = ) > 0 THEN

update yourtable set current = 0;

ELSE

insert into yourtable (client_id,member_id,current) values (value1,value2,value3)

Answer (score 2):

First of all check if the value exists in the table or not, by using a SELECT query.

Then check if the result haven't save value so it will be inserted, else show an error .

Answer (score 0):

This would be a great time to create a database stored procedure that flows something like...

```
select user
if exists update row
else insert new row
```

stored procedures don't improve transaction times, but they are a great addition to any piece of software.

If this doesn't solve your problem then a database trigger might help out.

Doing a little research on this matter might open up some great ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Add below logic in  your SP

```
If (select count(*) from yourtable where  client_id = <value> and member_id = <value>) > 0 THEN

update yourtable set current = 0;

ELSE

insert into yourtable (client_id,member_id,current) values (value1,value2,value3)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want simple solution then follow this:

```
 *) use select with each entry in selected team.
    if select returns a row 
   then use update sql
   else 
   use insert sql.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case member_id & client_id together makes the primary key.

So , you can use sql ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax.

Example:

```
    $sql="INSERT INTO table_name SET 
                        client_id='".$clientId."',
                        member_id='".$member_id."',
                        current='".$current."'
                        ON DUPLICATE KEY 
                        UPDATE 
                        current = '".$current."'
                        ";
```

In this case when member_id & client_id combination repeats , it will automatically executes update query for that particular row.